# Position of 'also'

Tags: adverbs, word-order

What is the correct position of the word 'also'?

> I would like to **also** talk about ...
>
> I would **also** like to talk about ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on what you want to say. Are you *also liking* or *also talking*? I.e. Are you trying to say that alongside liking something else, you would like to talk about ellipsis? Or alongside talking about something else, you would like to talk about ellipsis?

*Also* is an adverb, so it can go next to any of the verbs.

> 1. I (also would) like to talk about ...
> 2. I (would also) like to talk about ...
> 3. I would (also like) to talk about ...
> 4. I would (like also) to talk about ...
> 5. I would like (to also talk) about ...
> 6. ?I would like (to talk also) about ...
> 7. *I would like to talk about also ...

Number 7 is wrong in the context of wanting to talk about ellipsis. Number 6 is an unusual choice stylistically, I think it hints at a low confidence moment for the speaker, because the *also* is added in at the last possible moment.

Numbers 1 and 2 means that someone else is speaking about ellipsis and you have something to say as well, 2 has emphasis on *I* and possibly *also*.

Numbers 3 and 4 can mean this too, but they can also mean that as well as something else you are talking about you want to talk about ellipsis. 3 has emphasis on *also like* in the second context. 4 is more likely to be applied to the second context, to apply to the first context the emphasis would be on *I* and *also*.

Number 5 can only mean that as well as something else you are going to talk about ellipsis.

Comment: '_Also_ is an adverb, so it can go next to any of the verbs.' But _seldom_ is an adverb too. 
4': *I would (like seldom) to talk about ...