# Word order (just style or grammar)?

Tags: writing-style

I'm a German and thus speak a language that theoretically allows much more freedom in word order than English. But see...

1. **Also** it will be shown that...
2. It **also** will be shown that...
3. It will **also** be shown that...
4. It will be **also** shown that...
5. It will be shown **also** that...
6. It will be shown that **also**...

I speak English since half a century, but such details still elude me. Instinctively, I'd say all versions are legit by grammar, albeit some sounding very ugly, especially Nr.4. So, what do you say? Is there even a subtle semantic difference? What's a good style guide you could recommend for such questions?

Comment: I'd rate 4-6 as (at best) unidiomatic and 2 as borderline, and always opt for 3 or (usually with a comma) 1. Google Ngrams (omitting 'it') show that  3 is a favoured option by a distance.

Comment: Grammar is not a matter of arranging words in a line. You have to look at constituents; adverbs and many other little words tend to cluster at the boundaries between major constituents, especially in niches like the beginning, the ending, and after the first auxiliary verb.

Comment: I answered your main question below, but one other thing that's unrelated to it. Unlike _seit_ , the English word "since" can can only be used with reference to a fixed point in time. So, while "_ich bin seit 1984 hier_" becomes "I've been here since 1984", the usage "_ich habe es seit zwei Wochen_" has to be translated using "for" and the perfect past tense, as in: "I **have had** it **for** two weeks"  (Your English is, however, far better than my German!)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Position of 'also'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68568/position-of-also)

Comment: I agree with you that all six formulations are grammatically legit (convey the same meaning) and that some are uglier than others.

Comment: I find it amusing that answers are, all in all, so different. (@FumbleFingers: too bad SE's other-questions-hinter is not a psychic. I *knew* such a question must have been asked before)

Comment: @HaukeReddmann: I never use the built-in search facility on ELU or ELL. I think it works okay for other SO sites, but the way it defines and treats "noise words" means I get better results using a Google site-specific search here. I don't know if your question *will* get closed as a dup (that would still need 2 more closevotes, as I write), but I would just say I think *on average* the site is actually ***improved*** by having multiple questions about the same thing. Ideally with all but the "best" one closed as dups.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it:

1. Also, it will be shown that it is dead. - Adverbial free modifier modifying the whole sentence - usually followed by a comma.
2. It also will be shown that it is dead. – emphasises the future “will be shown”
3. It will also be shown that it is dead. . – emphasises the passive action of “be shown”.
4. It will be also shown that it is dead. – emphasises the showing aspect
5. It will be shown also that it is dead. – Also is itself emphasised and emphasises that the first attribute is not the only attribute.
6. It will be shown that, also, it is dead. – this ‘also’ is parenthetical, and not really essential.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a style guide you could use for answering this question.  #1 seems to me to be the best choice if previous sentences/paragraphs started with an expression of order or importance, such as, "Secondly, we can see..." or "The main result shows that..."  However, #1 does need a comma after Also.  (Can't cite a specific reference for needing a comma;  undoubtedly, someone else will.)

Sentence #2 will be favored by those who resist splitting verbs, similar to those who resist splitting infinitives.  #3 flows more easily off the tongue.  #4 - #6 sound to me as though someone speaks another language and is translating from the word order of the native language.  Good question!

Answer (score -1):

1. Also **,**  it will be shown that... ← **good** *(but needs the comma as indicated)*
2. It also will be shown that... ←  *breaks a word-ordering rule of English*
3. It will also be shown that... ← **good**
4. It will be also shown that... ← *adverb is incompatible with verb "* to show *", so not valid here*
5. It will be shown also that... ← *expecting a clause here, not an adverb*
6. It will be shown that also... ← *you can't start a that-clause with "also"*

Regarding semantic differences, I would say that by placing "also" into its own clause at the start of the sentence, Number 1 emphasises that this is an additional thing, whereas in Number 3 it's more of an incidental observation.

Your post got me wondering why the others are not natural, and here's what I came up with...

#### 1. Adverbial clauses at head of sentence - use a comma

As you wrote it, Number 1 is incorrect, but if you add a comma after "also", it's not only grammatically correct, but it's what I'd consider the preferred form in serious writing.

Here, "Also" is being used as a [adverbial clause](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-adverbial-clause-1689190): it provides an additional information about whatever is conveyed by the main clause of the sentence. In this case, the addition of "Also" indicates that *"it will be shown"* is something that is happening in addition to whatever you've previously written about.

Because "Also" is a sub-clause, it must be followed by a comma.

(This use of adverbial clauses is very common in written English. In fact, used one in  the previous paragraph: "Because 'Also' is a sub-clause")

#### 2. Don't get between a tense-marker and its subject - even when there's no subject!

Number 2 is wrong because in an English sentence, tense markers ("will", "was", "might", "had", etc.) are placed as close as possible to their subject-nouns. Your sentence has no subject (it's in the passive voice), and while that forces the *object* of the sentence to the beginning,  the tense marker must still sit as early in the sentence as possible after that.

However, here you have placed an adverb before the tense marker ("will"), and you're not allowed to do that.

#### 4. ambiguous adverb

"Also" is not modifying "shown", it's modifying the whole clause ("*[PASSIVE] will show it*"). However, where you've placed the word is where a verb modifier would normally sit.  That makes the instinctive reading of the sentence something like "*to show in an 'also' fashion*", which is nonsensical.

For contrast, look at an adverb that *would* modify "to show" placed here instead:

- It will be *comprehensively* shown that ...

Here, the natural reading is "*to show in a comprehensive fashion*", which makes sense.

#### 5. The verb is gone, you're too late!

by the time we get to "shown", the clause is finished: we've got a subject (the missing subject of the passive voice) a verb ("will be shown") and an object (an existential "it"). However, "to show" is in a category of verbs that can take two objects: what was shown, and who it was shown to. To describe *what* will be shown, we expect a [that-clause](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/that-clauses).  Nothing else is permitted without starting a new clause.  The adverb "also" isn't correct here.

#### 6. You can't start a "that-clause" with "also"

A "that-clause" breaks one general rule of English: it doesn't need to be set off with a comma. However, it is still a sub-clause, and that means that its contents must obey the normal English word-ordering rules. "Also" is an adverb, and as such, it cannot sit at the start of a clause.

"**But hang on, doesn't Number 1 start with "Also" as a clause??**"

Well, yes it does, but the usage in Number 1 is only permitted at the start of a sentence (or after a semicolon). It is not permitted in a regular subclause or a that-clause.